# Why Javascript event handler is called twice?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When I add an event handler to element of a class as follows:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="class1" id="div1">div1</div>

  <script>
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
    var onclick = function() {
      alert("clicked");
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].addEventListener("click", onclick);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The alert window is popped up twice if I click on the div element. But if I use the following code, the alert window is only popped up once.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="class1" id="div1">div1</div>
  <script>
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
    var onclick = function() {
      alert("clicked");
    }

    divs.addEventListener("click", onclick);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The following code also pops up the alert window twice:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="class1" id="div1">div1</div>

  <script>
    var div = document.getElementById("div1");
    var onclick = function() {
      alert("clicked");
    }
    div.addEventListener("click", onclick);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I wonder why the event handler is called twice, regardless I use  `addEventListener("click",onclick, true);` or `addEventListener("click",onclick,false);`

I use Firefox browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because your `onclick` variable is a global variable, and that means you are essentially doing this when you assign the function to `onclick`:

```
window.onclick = function () {
    alert('click');
};
```

So you are adding the event listener to your `div`s, *and* `window`, and when you click the `div`, it is firing once on the `div`, and once on the `window`.

To avoid this, use an iife to shield your variables from the global scope:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="class1" id="div1">div1</div>

  <script>
    (function () {
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
        var onclick = function() {
          alert("clicked");
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
          divs[i].addEventListener("click", onclick);
        }
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Better is to rename and delegate

Comment: @mplungjan Rename and delegate? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @mplungjan Delegation is fine, but I don't think it's any better or worse than assigning the event handler to each `div`. There are times when delegation is better, but I don't think this is one of them. As for renaming, we should be avoiding pollution of the global scope regardless, so there isn't really a need to rename. And your answer is ok as a suggestion of an alternate approach, but you didn't answer OP's question.

Comment: As I answer, if there is only one div, then there is no need to loop either. And I would use an anonymous function anyway

Answer (score 2):

Why loop at all. Apart from the name (you overwrite the native onclick) issue, why not just add once? You have only one div with a unique ID.

Using an anonymous function makes it even safer not to accidentally use a native function name

```js
const div = document.getElementById("div1");

div.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

```html
<div class="class1" id="div1">div1</div>
```

NOTE: Be careful using [anonymous functions in a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#memory_issues) though.
I never do so we are safe here

If you have more than one element to use the same event handler, I always recommend to delegate

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const div = e.target.closest("div");
  if (div && div.matches(".class1")) {
    alert(div.id + " clicked");
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="class1" id="div1">div1</div>
  <div class="class1" id="div2">div2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was to force that the `addEventListener` to be called once.

Like:

```
   if (!window.onClickListenerAdded) {
      const onClickListener = (event) => {
        alert("clicked");
      };
      window.removeEventListener('click', onClickListener);
      window.addEventListener('click', onClickListener);
      window.onClickListenerAdded = true;
    }
```